# Check Similarity String Between Column In Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a table in the link below:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EOALaBVzHijUP_8dM1Sr7KTutdTah8b9Q0xDRoNHBLo/edit#gid=0

[image]

if the text is split first, then check what do you do? for example "Kebumen District Office" Vs "District Head Office of Kebumen District" Then we need 7x7 columns = 49 columns because we will match for each word words 1-1, 1-2, 1-3, 1-4, 2-1, 2-2.2-3.2-4, etc. 
The text in column B is split and then checked for each word with the text in column A. If in column B there are many different words found the text is not similar.

Only I am still confused to make the formula. Please give me the solution sir. Thanks.

Comment: Please add all variants of input data and results you want right in the question. The link to the file is good when you're doing with some data model, but also good to include a picture of your data.

Comment: I have already added sir, please the solution sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matching patterns are very different in your case and I see no solution based on formulas (regular expressions).

You may need to find articles about `fuzzy vlookup`.

Here's what I found for google sheets (not tested):

- **Addon**, [find fuzzy matches](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/find-fuzzy-matches/cadkkijbhldndjaflcbapfllpolajpcp?hl=en)

This problem is [common for Excel](http://fuzzy%20vlookup%20in%20Excel), there're solutions based on [vba](/questions/tagged/vba).

---

As I said, the one formula won't solve your task because you have many cases. First example `Mc Donald` vs `McDonald` is checked easily with a formula:

`= substitute(A, " ", "") = substitute(B, " ", "")`

Your next samples are different. You may use some code, but even this won't give the expected results. My suggestion: split the task into small cases and try to solve them separately. Make an investigation or ack a new question for each case.

---

Your second and 3-d lines are case2. In this case, you need to check all the words in A are also in B. You'll need to try solving it and ask another question if needed. And so on.

Comment: if the text is split first, then check what do you do?
for example "Kebumen District Office" Vs "District Head Office of Kebumen District" Then we need 7x7 columns = 49 columns

because we will match for each word
words 1-1, 1-2, 1-3, 1-4, 2-1, 2-2.2-3.2-4, etc.

only I am still confused to make the formula

Comment: the text in column B is split and then checked for each word with the text in column A. If in column B there are many different words found the text is not similar.

Comment: Please see my edit to the answer. Looks like your question is multiple questions in one. No way to answer it fully.

Comment: @lutfi-creativesys, I'm sorry, I have nothing to add to my answer. Hope this was helpful info.

Comment: thank you for the solution sir. fuzzy vlookup keywords have really helped my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Fuzzy matching is definitely the way to go. Different algorithms have different strengths and weaknesses. My suggestion is that you visit the G Suite marketplace and look for a tool I created called **Flookup** or simply follow this link:

- [Flookup Data Wrangler](https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/app/flookup/593806014962)

It'll allow you to look for matches ranging from 0% to 100% similarity. The basic formula is:

```
FLOOKUP(lookupValue, tableArray, lookupCol, indexNum, [threshold], [rank])
```

Find out more from the [official website](https://www.getflookup.com/).

**Edit:** I'm the creator of Flookup

Comment: Flookup looks very interesting but it's suspiciously anonymous. The terms and conditions are an Apache license, but without a link to the source code. Is this meant to be open-source?

Comment: _suspiciously anonymous_? What information would you require to put your suspicions to rest.
The code was initially meant to be open source but I changed my mind after a few updates. Changes to the license will be added soon.

Comment: Hi, @Andrew, it's impossible to find out anything about the author(s), and the inconsistency between the license and the lack of links to source was raising red flags. I can't link flookup to any reputable source, or any source at all. Hence it looks anonymous, and that's suspicious. Open up the code, or say who the author(s) are on the site please.

Comment: @Jacek thank you for your feedback and suggestion. I'll add information about the author (me) on the website and possibly the underlying logic the add-on uses. Otherwise, I updated the license to reflect the state of the add-on better. That said, please be rest assured that the add-on is completely safe to use and I'm willing to answer any privacy/security related questions about it.